# Parsec: parsing expressions with variables that start with '$' (no whitespace)

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to parse expressions with variables that start with a `$` (as in `$a=$b`), using Parsec's Token and Expr modules. Here is a reduced version of my code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Applicative

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

import qualified Text.Parsec.Token    as Tok
import qualified Text.Parsec.Language as Tok
import qualified Text.Parsec.Expr     as Ex

data Expr
  = BinaryOp String Expr Expr
  | Var String
  deriving (Show)

lexer :: Tok.TokenParser ()
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser style
  where
    style = Tok.emptyDef
      { Tok.reservedOpNames = ["="]
      , Tok.reservedNames   = []
      , Tok.identStart      = letter
      , Tok.identLetter     = alphaNum
      }

reservedOp = Tok.reservedOp lexer
identifier = Tok.identifier lexer
whiteSpace = Tok.whiteSpace lexer

parseExpr :: String -> Either ParseError Expr
parseExpr = parse (whiteSpace *> expr <* eof) ""

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = Ex.buildExpressionParser opTable terms <?> "expression"
  where
    opTable =
      [ [ Ex.Infix (reservedOp "=" >> return (BinaryOp "=")) Ex.AssocLeft ] ]
    terms =
      try var

var :: Parser Expr
var = Var <$> (char '$' >> identifier)

--

main :: IO ()
main = case parseExpr "$a=$b" of
  Left err -> print err
  Right expr -> print expr
```

This works fine for expressions with whitespace around the operators (like `$a = $b`), but without whitespace (`$a=$b`) I get the error:

```
(line 1, column 5):
unexpected '$'
expecting operator
```

Also, if I modify the parser to parse variables that don't start with a `$`, the parser works with and without whitespace. So there seems to be a problem with the combination of `$` and operators that don't have whitespace between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the definition of `opStart` and `opLetter` in the default token parser:

```
emptyDef   :: LanguageDef st
emptyDef    = LanguageDef
               { commentStart   = ""
               ...
               , opStart        = opLetter emptyDef
               , opLetter       = oneOf ":!#$%&*+./<=>?@\\^|-~"
               ...
               }
```

The token parser greedily matches an operator name using `opStart` and `opLetter`, so `$a=$b` parses the same as `$a =$ b`. and since `=$` is not a operator you get the syntax error.

If you remove `$` from `opLetter` things should work, e.g.:

```
lexer :: Tok.TokenParser ()
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser style
  where
    style = Tok.emptyDef
      { Tok.reservedOpNames = ["="]
      , Tok.reservedNames   = []
      , Tok.identStart      = letter
      , Tok.identLetter     = alphaNum
      , Tok.opLetter        = oneOf ":!#%"  -- add this line
      }
```